# How to register GraphServiceClient in ASP.NET Core 6.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the GraphServiceClient to get `user.Department` in the following controller:

```
namespace ExternalApp.Areas.Budget.Controllers
{
    public class Controller : BaseController
    {
        private readonly BudgetDbContext _db;
        private readonly GraphServiceClient _client;

        public Controller(
            ILogger<BaseController> logger,
            BudgetDbContext db,
            GraphServiceClient client) : base(logger)
        {
            _db = db;
            _client = client;
        }

        public async Task<JsonResult> GetVehicleAcquisitions()
        {
            var data = _db.VehicleAcquisitions.AsQueryable();

            var user = await _client.Me.GetAsync();

            if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
                data = _db.VehicleAcquisitions
                    .Where(x => x.GlSegment3.SSegment3Desc
                        .Contains(user.Department))
                    .AsQueryable();

            // Other code
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient' while attempting to activate 'ExternalApp.Areas.Budget.Controllers.Controller'

I have tried registering the `GraphServiceClient` in `Program.cs`. The examples that I get seem to be outdated because they reference things that are not recognized, such as `InteractiveBrowserProvider` and `DelegateAuthenticationProvider`.

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(hostContext.Configuration);
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<BudgetDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration
        .GetConnectionString("BudgetEntities"))
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
);

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this line in your Program.cs file.

```
// we need to register GraphServiceClient
builder.Services.AddSingleton<GraphServiceClient>(graphServiceClient);
```

The code above can't use it directly, because there are some configurations for `GraphServiceClient`. Here is the sample for you, for more details, you can check this thread([How to use DI with Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66530968/7687666)).

```
  // Initialize the client credential auth provider
  IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
      .Create(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppId"))
      .WithTenantId(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TenantId"))
      .WithClientSecret(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientSecret"))
      .Build();
  ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
  GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
  // Set up the Microsoft Graph service client with client credentials
  builder.Services.AddSingleton<GraphServiceClient>(graphServiceClient);
```

Comment: It looks like `ClientCredentialProvider` is part of `Microsoft.Graph.Auth`, which is deprecated.

Comment: I also need delegated authentication flow for `_client.Me`.

Comment: Hi @csharpdev, I just point the issue, since I don't have your project, what I can do just show the sample. Could you check the link in my answer, it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the department value with the following changes:

Program.cs:

Replaced

```
builder.Host.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(hostContext.Configuration);
});
```

With

```
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Controller.cs:

```
private readonly BudgetDbContext _db;
private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

public VehicleAcquisitionController(
    ILogger<BaseController> logger,
    BudgetDbContext db,
    GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient) : base(logger)
{
    _db = db;
    _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
}

public async Task<JsonResult> MyResults()
{
    var data = _db.VehicleAcquisitions.AsQueryable();

    var result = await _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
    {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "department" };
    });

    if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
        data = data
            .Where(x => x.GlSegment3.SSegment3Desc
                .Contains(result.Department));
    
    //Other code
}
```